# Overriding toString method - public/private access

Tags: javascript, prototype, tostring

I have a basic library I created as follows:

```
(function () {
    function Store() {
        var store = [];

        if (!(this instanceof Store)) {
            return new Store();
        }

        this.add = function (name, price) {
            store.push(new StoreItem(name, price));
            return this;
        };
    }

    function StoreItem(name, price) {
        if (!(this instanceof StoreItem)) {
            return new StoreItem();
        }

        this.Name = name || 'Default item';
        this.Price = price || 0.0;
    }

    Store.prototype.toString = function () {
        // build a formatted string here
    };

    StoreItem.prototype.toString = function () {
        return this.Name + ' $' + this.Price;
    };

    window.shop = window.shop || {
        Store: function () {
            return new Store();
        }
    };
}());
```

The large majority of this works well! However, I do not want to expose my `store` array defined in the Store constructor as I do not want it modified in anyway outside this library's control.

But, on the contrary, I would like to override the `Store`'s `toString` method to make use of the `StoreItem`s in the `store` array so I can return a formatted string of all the `StoreItem`s using its `toString` method.

E.g. if `store` was exposed, the `toString` method would look something like:

```
Store.prototype.toString = function () {
    return this.store.join('\r\n');
};

// shop.Store().add('Bread', 2).add('Milk', 1.5).toString() result:
// Bread $2
// Milk $1.5
```

Is there anyway I can achieve this without exposing my `store` array publicly?

Answer (score 2):

You can give each `Store` it's own `.toString` method, being privileged to access the local `store` variable through closure - just like you did with `.add`:

```
function Store() {
    if (!(this instanceof Store)) {
        return new Store();
    }
    var store = [];

    this.add = function(name, price) {
        store.push(new StoreItem(name, price));
        return this;
    };
    this.toString = function () {
        return store.join('\n');
    };
}
```

Alternatively, you will have to define some kind of accessor method anyway, or your `store` would be useless if you only can add to it but never read it. Something will need to display the store items, will need to iterate them, will need to test them for availability… If you create a generic accessor, maybe in form of some iterator (an `each` method with a callback?), then a `.prototype.toString` method could use that as well.

Comment: I don't get this... What on earth would prevent me from doing stuff like this: var bla = new Store(); bla.toString; <- contains the function...

Comment: @OddDev: So what? The function is not the `store` array. OP wants to hide the `store`, not the `toString` method.

Comment: Plus 1 – this seems to be the simplest way.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to keep the prototype toString method whilst protecting `store`, by adding a public method that returns the stringified `store`, and calling it from `Store.prototype.toString`.

Below I added `this.getStoreString` to the constructor, and called it from the original `toString`.

```
(function () {
    function Store() {
        var store = [];

        if (!(this instanceof Store)) {
            return new Store();
        }

        this.add = function (name, price) {
            store.push(new StoreItem(name, price));
            return this;
        };

        // new method
        this.getStoreString = function(){
            return store.join('\r\n');  
        };
    }

    function StoreItem(name, price) {
        if (!(this instanceof StoreItem)) {
            return new StoreItem();
        }

        this.Name = name || 'Default item';
        this.Price = price || 0.0;
    }

    Store.prototype.toString = function () {
        // call the new method
        return this.getStoreString();
    };

    StoreItem.prototype.toString = function () {
        return this.Name + ' $' + this.Price;
    };

    window.shop = window.shop || {
        Store: function () {
            return new Store();
        }
    };
}());
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/900hpgkm/)**

@Bergi's answer seems simpler though, but this shows another option.